# Distance calculation on matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I am trying to implement a K-means algorithm in Python (I know there is libraries for that, but I want to learn how to implement it myself.) Here is the function I am havin problem with:

```
def AssignPoints(points, centroids):
    """
    Takes two arguments:
    points is a numpy array such that points.shape = m , n where m is number of examples,
    and n is number of dimensions.

    centroids is numpy array such that centroids.shape = k , n where k is number of centroids.
    k < m should hold.

    Returns:
    numpy array A such that A.shape = (m,) and A[i] is index of the centroid which points[i] is assigned to.
    """

    m ,n = points.shape
    temp = []
    for i in xrange(n):
        temp.append(np.subtract.outer(points[:,i],centroids[:,i]))
    distances = np.hypot(*temp)
    return distances.argmin(axis=1)
```

Purpose of this function, given m points in n dimensional space, and k centroids in n dimensional space, produce a numpy array of (x1 x2 x3 x4 ... xm) where x1 is the index of centroid which is closest to first point. This was working fine, until I tried it with 4 dimensional examples. When I try to put 4 dimensional examples, I get this error:

```
  File "/path/to/the/kmeans.py", line 28, in AssignPoints
    distances = np.hypot(*temp)
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

How can I fix this, or if I can't, how do you suggest I calculate what I am trying to calculate here?

### My Answer

```
def AssignPoints(points, centroids):
    m ,n = points.shape
    temp = []
    for i in xrange(n):
        temp.append(np.subtract.outer(points[:,i],centroids[:,i]))
    for i in xrange(len(temp)):
        temp[i] = temp[i] ** 2
    distances = np.add.reduce(temp) ** 0.5
    return distances.argmin(axis=1)
```

Comment: You realize that `len(temp) == n` and that `np.hypot` admits only three arguments, don't you?

Comment: To be honest, what np.hypot does isn't very clear to me. I merely copied that from another question when I was first writing that function. I thought that would have work no matter the dimensions. How do you suggest I should write this function?

Comment: `np.hypot` calculates hypotenuses of triangles. It admits two arguments: `leg1` and `leg2`, and a third optional one, which is where to put the result. The idea, of course, is to calculate a lot of hypotenuses in one go, and so `leg1` and `leg2` are supposed to be arrays, containing each one the respective legs of the `n` triangles you want to calculate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
np.sqrt(((points[np.newaxis] - centroids[:,np.newaxis]) ** 2).sum(axis=2)).argmin(axis=0)
```

Or:

```
diff = points[np.newaxis] - centroids[:,np.newaxis]
norm = np.sqrt((diff*diff).sum(axis=2))
closest = norm.argmin(axis=0)
```

And don't ask what's it doing :D

Edit: nah, just kidding. The broadcasting in the middle (`points[np.newaxis] - centroids[:,np.newaxis]`) is "making" two 3D arrays from the original ones. The result is such that each "plane" contains the difference between all the points and one of the centroids. Let's call it `diffs`.

Then we do the usual operation to calculate the euclidean distance (square root of the squares of differences): `np.sqrt((diffs ** 2).sum(axis=2))`. We end up with a `(k, m)` matrix where row 0 contain the distances to `centroids[0]`, etc. So, the `.argmin(axis=0)` gives you the result you wanted.

Comment: I think this is the best approach and as @RicardoCárdenes has shown you can do it all on one line, but please, for the sake of anyone who ever has to read your code, don't.

Comment: OP's solution does 2 for loops, mine does 1, and yours does 0...so yours is the best.  As is usually the case, it is also harder to read

Comment: @Bago: actually... my point was not making it in just one line ;), but to avoid loops. The one-liner was actually just a side effect O:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a distance function where you are using hypot.  Usually in K-means it is
Distance=sum((point-centroid)^2)
Here is some matlab code that does it ... I can port it if you can't, but give it a go.  Like you said, only way to learn.

```
function idx = findClosestCentroids(X, centroids)
%FINDCLOSESTCENTROIDS computes the centroid memberships for every example
%   idx = FINDCLOSESTCENTROIDS (X, centroids) returns the closest centroids
%   in idx for a dataset X where each row is a single example. idx = m x 1 
%   vector of centroid assignments (i.e. each entry in range [1..K])
%

% Set K
K = size(centroids, 1);

[numberOfExamples numberOfDimensions] = size(X);
% You need to return the following variables correctly.
idx = zeros(size(X,1), 1);


% Go over every example, find its closest centroid, and store
%               the index inside idx at the appropriate location.
%               Concretely, idx(i) should contain the index of the centroid
%               closest to example i. Hence, it should be a value in the 
%               range 1..K
%
for loop=1:numberOfExamples
    Distance = sum(bsxfun(@minus,X(loop,:),centroids).^2,2);
    [value index] = min(Distance);
    idx(loop) = index;
end;


end
```

UPDATE

This should return the distance, notice that the above matlab code just returns the distance(and index) of the closest centroid...your function returns all distances, as does the one below.

```
def FindDistance(X,centroids):
K=shape(centroids)[0]
examples, dimensions = shape(X)
distance = zeros((examples,K))
for ex in xrange(examples):
    distance[ex,:] = np.sum((X[ex,:]-centroids)**2,1)
return distance
```

Comment: So I have to calculate the distances for each points seperately in a loop?

Comment: You should be able to do it in the for loop you already have, just define Distance[i] in the for loop instead of temp...hold on and I'll see if I haven't done this

Comment: @yasar11732 actually... you should be able to do it in one go... but that depends on the size of the sample (or, if you prefer it, on the amount of RAM you can devote to this). Let's see if I can come up with it...

Comment: Thanks, I came up with a slightly different approach. You may want to see my answer on my question.